# Zend Framework 2 Routing subdomains to module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

After searching a long time with no success.
before I give up, I would like to ask:

Is there a way to route a subdomain to a module in **Zend Framework 2**? like:

**Subdomain** => **Module**
api.site.com => api
dev.site.com => dev
admin.site.com => admin
site.com => public
...

I tried doing it like this but I can't get access to controllers other than the default (Index).

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => 'site.com',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            )
        )
    ),
),
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 doesn't have a notion of routing to modules; all routing mappings are between a URI pattern (for HTTP routes) and a specific controller class.  That said, `Zend\Mvc` provides an event listener ([`Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/ModuleRouteListener.php)) which allows you to define a URI pattern that maps to multiple controllers based on a given pattern, and so emulates "module routing".  To define such a route, you would place this as your routing configuration:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
         // This defines the hostname route which forms the base
         // of each "child" route
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => 'site.com',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This Segment route captures the requested controller
                // and action from the URI and, through ModuleRouteListener,
                // selects the correct controller class to use
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Index',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

([Click here to see an example of this @ ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L23))

This is only half of the equation, though.  You must also register every controller class in your module using a specific naming format.  This is also done through the same configuration file:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
```

The array key is the alias ModuleRouteListener will use to find the right controller, and it must be in the following format:

```
<Namespace>\<Controller>\<Action>
```

The value assigned to this array key is the fully-qualified name of the controller class.

([Click here to see an example of this @ ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L70))

NOTE:  IF you aren't using ZendSkeletonApplication, or have removed it's default Application module, you will need to register the ModuleRouteListener in one of your own modules.  [Click here to see an example of how ZendSkeletonApplication registers this listener](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php#L21)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations clear and precise. I took your solution. I struggled so much on this.

Comment: i use mamp pro and i create a subdomain on my virtual host name so after i use reseller.myhost.com/test it is okey but if i write reseller.myhost.com it goes to index of application not indexaction of my module

Comment: @Sapher but why other routes of other modules work yet on current subdomain ?

Answer (score 4):

If i understand slide #39 of [DASPRIDS Rounter Presentation](http://stuff.dasprids.de/slides/zendcon2012/introducing-the-new-zend-framework-2-router/presentation.html#1) correctly, it's as simple as - on a per module basis - to define your subdomain hosts, i.e.:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => 'api.site.com',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Api\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            )
        )
    ),
),
```

Etc, you'd do this for every Module on its own.

Comment: Sorry if it seems dumb but do you have to register new webserver virtual host for api subdomain?