# ZF2 routing by subdomain (Hostname)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I added a subdomain on my myhost.com: reseller.myhost.com and I want it to route to my 'Reseller' module.  I read this question :[zend-framework-2-routing-subdomains-to-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070824/zend-framework-2-routing-subdomains-to-module)

my reseller routing is this:

```
   //Routing of User
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(


        'Reseller' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => 'reseller.myhost.com',
                'constraints' => array(

                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Reseller\Controller\Reseller',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,

            'child_routes' => array(
                'login' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/login',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action'     => 'login',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'createAd' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/createAd',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action'     => 'createAd',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),


            ),
        )
    ))
```

I expect to it go to the Reseller index action, but it instead goes to Application's index action.  What  should i do?

If I visit url reseller.myhost.com/login everything is ok, but if i call reseller.myhost.com it goes to index of application module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZF2 Routing by Hostname works with other modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135038/zf2-routing-by-hostname-works-with-other-modules)

Comment: You should not post a question twice.