# ZF2 Routing by Hostname works with other modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

I added a `reseller` subdomain on my `myhost.com` (`reseller.myhost.com`) and I use it for routing to my `Reseller` module.  Read this question I posted before here: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070824/zend-framework-2-routing-subdomains-to-module)

My `Reseller` route config looks this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'Reseller' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => 'reseller.myhost.com',
                'constraints' => array(

                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Reseller\Controller\Reseller',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'home' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Reseller\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Reseller',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                         ),
                    ),
                ),

            )
        )
    )
)
```

My `createdAd` route matches on reseller.myhost.com/createdAd but I expect routes from other modules not work on this `reseller` subdomain.

and here is my advertise route configuration

```
    'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'locate' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/locate[/:cityName][/:CityId][/:CategoryId][/:categoryName]',
                     'constraints' => array(

                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),


             'createAd' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/createAd[/:subCategoryId]',
                     'constraints' => array(

                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                         'action'     => 'createAd',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),




         ),
     ),


 ));
```

be notice that i want to advertise module work without subdomain and work normally and only reseller module work with subdomain

Why does this occur?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Can you please add some more details. What is expected? What is happening? What does the route config look like in the "other modules" that you mention.

Comment: @Wilt my firend i excpet to route of reseller.myhost.com/createAdvertise dosent work beacuse createAdvertise route defined in advertise controller not in ResellerController

Answer (score 0):

*I understand from your question: you expect the `createAd` route not to work on the subdomain. So `reseller.myhost.com/createdAd` should not match instead you want a to match on the route without subdomain `myhost.com/createdAd`.*

I would suggest that you should create a separate route definition for the `Advertise` module.

Your route config in `Advertise` module (`module/Advertise/config/module.config.php`)

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
        )
        'createAd' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/createAd',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                    'action'     => 'createAd',
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Your route config in `Reseller` module (`module/Reseller/config/module.config.php`)

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'Reseller' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => ':reseller.myhost.com',
            ),
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'home' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Reseller\Controller\Reseller',
                            'action'     => 'index'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

You can distinguish matches because of the subdomain.

The routes `home` and `createAdd` match the `Advertise` module without subdomain.

The route `reseller.home` matches the index in `Reseller` module within subdomain `reseller.myhost.com`.

Check for more details also the Hostname routing example [here in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#http-routing-examples)

Comment: let me i update my question to can help u completely

Comment: i updated my question please read my updated question and 2 line in the end be notice section thank you

Comment: be notice that i want to advertise module work without subdomain and work normally and only reseller module work with subdomain

Comment: ok so by this change my route changes to  home/createAd? cause before i only call $this->url('createAd') yeah ?

Comment: so by this, the main problem not solved yet i can route reseller.myhost.com/createAd

Comment: please help me to findout why creatAd router still works with this subdomain if i write reseller.myhost.com/createAd it goes to that page why ?

Comment: my friend did you see my comments

Answer (score 0):

You should have a "root" hostname for all your standard routes not on the subdomain route. Eg:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'myhost' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => 'myhost.com',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now you can add your 'createAd' route (and other routes) as a child route of the 'myhost' route. Eg:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'myhost' => [
            'child_routes' => [
                'createAd' => array(
                     'type'    => 'segment',
                     'options' => array(
                         'route'    => '/createAd[/:subCategoryId]',
                         'constraints' => array(

                         ),
                         'defaults' => array(
                             'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                             'action'     => 'createAd',
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ],
         ],
     ],
],
```