# Adding a new route in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I would like to add a new route (link) to my ZF2 application like following:

```
mysite.com/somename/?invitecode=12345
```

Please note that **/somename/** shouldn't be controller, but merely just a name in link which is used for tracking purposes. I figured I could do this by adding a new controller, but since this name is going to be dynamic, I can't use controller for this. I have  found this in the module.config.php file:

```
 'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

I tried adding a path here like this just for testing purposes:

```
'application/index/indextest' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
```

And I've tried accessing the URL like this:

```
mysite.com/index/indextest
```

But the only way I can access this link is if I add an action in the controller like this:

```
public function indextestAction()
{
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl("/");
}
```

Please note that the:

```
mysite.com/THISNAMEHERE/?invitecode=12345
```

Please note that **THISNAMEHERE** is dynamic, and varies upon what is written in my vhost's config file.

### What am I supposed to do here? Can someone help me out with this please?

EDIT:

Guys I've done the following so far, I have added a new controller with a name of "InviteController" which does the following check:

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
        if(!empty(htmlspecialchars($_GET["inviter"])))
        {
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl("/user/emailsignup");
        }
    }
```

I've added the controller to the invokables list like following:

```
 'Application\Controller\Invite' => 'Application\Controller\InviteController',
```

And in my module.config.php file:

```
'invite' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/invite/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Invite',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

So now when I try to access the URL it is like following:

```
  mysite.com/**invite**/?inviter=12345
```

However this is still not what I want... I need this bolded part (INVITE) to be dynamic. Basically if I'm accessing the app from a different vhost it would be like this:

```
mysite.com/vhost1name/?inviter=1234
```

And I'd still like it to invoke the InviteController and Index action within that controller.

Edit #2: Finally solved it! Thanks to @Wilt for the links and explanation! :)

Just in case anyone wonders, this is the solution:

```
'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Invite',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing for your ZF2 application is configured in your router config. The router config for a ZF2 module is most commonly stored inside the `module.config.php` file inside the module `config` folder:

```
/module/MyModuleName/config/module.config.php
```

The router config looks like this:

```
// This is your router config
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        // config goes here
    ),
),
```

You can read more on routing in the ZF2 documentation chapter **[Routing and controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)**

What you refer to in your question is a `view_manager` config not a `router` config.

If you are not familiar with basic concepts like routing and router config I would strongly suggest to follow a tutorial to get to know these basics before you work on your own application. The [ZF2 tutorial skeleton application (also known as the album application)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html) is a good starting point. Following the steps in the tutorial will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Hey @Wilt I have setup a route but its still not what I require. I've updated m question above. can you check it out ?

Comment: @perkes456 I don't see a route config in your question. Can you add it?

Comment: Hi Wilt, my apologies, I've updated the question , its there now.

Comment: P.S. I've updated the answer with what I'd like to make out of route that I'm entering, I hope it will make sense...

Comment: So basically what I'm trying to make is to make that part of url dynamic, but to make it still invoke the index action within the invite controller.... like   instead of /invite/?inviter=1238 to invoke dynamically like this /whichevernameishere/?inviter=1238 -> invoke index action of the Invite controller...

Comment: @perkes456 You defined a static route, you should make your route dynamic. There are a lot of examples online, just search for ***dynamic routing ZF2***.

Comment: Yes its static unfortunately... I have searched a lot but haven't found a solution to what I'm looking for... Could you help me out ?

Comment: @perkes456 If you want dynamic host names you should do something like in [this blog post](http://briangallagher.ie/2013/01/29/hostname-subdomain-routing-and-urls-using-zf2/) or [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13071724/1697459)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112693/discussion-between-perkes456-and-wilt).

Comment: thanks for the links, I've finally solved it! You're the best! :)